# Meta Box Not Showing up in The Admin Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

Using WordPress 3.7.1 and PHP 5.4.12 I am trying to add a Meta box - text field to my Custom Post Type. My custom Post Type name is "news" and this is my code:

```
<?php
/* Custom Meta Boxex */
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_cmbox_add');
add_action('save_post', 'save_options');
function my_cmbox_add()
{
    add_meta_box(
        "prodInfo-meta",
        "News Source ",
        "news_source",
        "news",
        "normal",
        "low"
    );
}
function news_source()
{
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $source = $custom['source'][0];

?>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo '<label>News Source :</label>'; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo '<input name="source" value="'. $source . '" style="width:250px;" />'; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
function save_options()
{
    global $post;
    if (!isset($_POST['source']) || $post->post_type != 'news')
    {
        return $post;
    }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "source", $_POST['source']);

}
```

I am not getting any error but as I said nothing show up in the page. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass parameters .

```
function my_cmbox_add()( $post_type, $post );
```

You can also try and use `add_meta_boxes_{post_type}` for best practice.

Comment: Thanks the `add_meta_boxes_{post_type}` naming practice actually got my meta boxes to work correctly!